# Giving camuflage to home page image that isn't wide enough

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make one of these modern designs where there's a carousel of images in the top of the home page of the webpage.

I am using Bootstrap 3 and so far I have managed to make it behave the way it should, but I feel like that's only going to happen in my screen, because I worked partially with fixed proportions so the images would look perfect in my screen, so they all have the same width and height. Here's how it looks:

[image]

If these images are displayed in a thinner screen I guess there would be no problem, or would there? I still have to test this, but I am pretty sure that there would not be any problem; anyway this is not that much of a concern for me right now, I am focused in the other issue. But if they're displayed in a wider screen an ugly border will appear, just like this:

[image]

That looks really bad, I think that I should center the image and treat those borders in a way that goes well along with the image, like if both image and borders were one whole. Any ideas?

Also I would need to reposition the carousel slide buttons to be fitted in the image instead outside. I am not that sure about how to do that either.

Here the code in case you need it:

```
<!-- Carousel -->
<div class="this-centrar-contenido this-margen-vertical">
  <div id="carousel-inicio" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#carousel-inicio" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel-inicio" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel-inicio" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel-inicio" data-slide-to="3"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel-inicio" data-slide-to="4"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="img/img1.jpg">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
         text
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="img/img2.jpg">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          text
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="img/img3.png">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          text
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="img/img4.png">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          text
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="img/img5.png">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          text
        </div>
      </div>
    </div> <!-- /.carousel-inner -->
  </div> <!-- /#carousel-inicio -->

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-inicio" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left this-icono-grande"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-inicio" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right this-icono-grande"></span>
  </a>
</div> <!-- /.col-md-12 -->
<!-- /Carousel -->
```

And custom css (the rest is Bootstrap 3 default for carousels)

```
.carousel-control
{
    height: 600px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For fitting the images I would use the images as background-images for each div.item, and set `background-size: cover;` in the css. For that each div.item needs an id or a specific class:

HTML:

```
<!-- Wrapper for slides -->
<div class="carousel-inner">

  <div id="img_1" class="item active">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
     text
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="img_2" class="item">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      text
    </div>
  </div>

  ...

  <div id="img_5" class="item">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      text
    </div>
  </div>

</div> <!-- /.carousel-inner -->
```

CSS:

```
#img_1 {
background: url('img/img1.png') no-repeat center center;
background-size: cover;
}

#img_2 {
background: url('img/img2.png') no-repeat center center;
background-size: cover;
}

...

#img_5 {
background: url('img/img2.png') no-repeat center center;
background-size: cover;
}
```

Now, you won't have any problem with the different viewports. Change the size of your browser's window to test it.

Comment: could you specify what can or can't be seen?